# break в тернарном операторе

Tags: php

Я что-то делаю не так?

```
$i==3 ? break : $i++ ;
```

Не получаю ожидаемый результат.

Comment: Тернарный оператор это сокращенная запись  `if/else`. Какой там может быть `break` ?

Comment: Алексей, поэтому и спрашиваю, что вас так удивляет ))) Получается что тернарный оператор не повторяет фунционал if/else полностью, как я думал.

Comment: Даже в обычном `if` нету `break`. В отрыве от циклов это сама по себе бессмысленная конструкция

Comment: Что за бред ))) Выход из цикла может быть выполнен через форму if в php. Тем более данный пример я использовал как раз для цикла, просто код не весь указываю что бы пользователям было удобней понять ситуацию.

Comment: Перечитайте еще раз то, что я написал для углубленного осознания....... и покажите где у вас в вопросе цикл?

Comment: `что бы пользователям было удобней понять ситуацию` - именно это сразу и сбивает .... и получилось что вы показали некий бред

Comment: Алексей, если бы я добавил данную конструкцию в таком виде while($rownewbuild = mysql_fetch_array($newbuild)){
     $name_metro = '<a href="#" title="'.$rownewbuild['name-metro'].'">'.$rownewbuild['name-metro'].'</a>';  
    $i=1; 
    echo '<div class="cont-33 left">
     <a class="thumb" href="#" title="">
      <img src="./img/zhk-1.jpg" class="wow fadeIn" alt="">
      <div class="back-hover"></div>
     </a>
     <a class="title" href="#" title="">ЖК '.$rownewbuild['zhk-name'].'</a>
     
      
     </div>
    </div>';
 
  
if($i==3){break;}else{$i++ ;}   

 }?>

Comment: Что это поменяло бы? Если суть вопроса состоит в том, что не работает данное выражение $i==3 ? break : $i++ ; потому что в тернарном выражении нельзя вернуть break В чём претензия?

Comment: Сравни: **не получается убить.** и вот это: **лежу в больнице, скучно, что бы ни придумал  - не получается убить время**............разница есть.... Так что да. Контекст важен.

Comment: ибо `Я что-то делаю не так?` глядя на представленную строку показывает одно - да, делаешь не так... потому что `break` нету в операторе `if` с какой стороны не подходи..... а вот вопрос "делаю цикл и хочу прервать его выполнение, но если с помощью конструкции if (....) это полчается сделать, то с помощью тернарного оператора ....... — нет. Почему?" - разница есть... **if с break** и **цикл с break** - почувствуй разницу

Comment: и да `Не получаю ожидаемый результат.` - как, например, из этого можно было вообще знать что ты пишешь это в цикле и ожидаешь что он прервется? Даже не написал чего ты в принципе ожидаешь. Может ты ожидаешь возведения в степень. Это я к чему - лучше в следующий раз поподробнее опиши (не 5 листов конечно) что конкретно делаешь   и **что именно** ожидаешь. Думаю из-за непонятно-телепатическипризывательного оформленного вопроса тут и висит 2 минуса...

Comment: А как бы вы написали данное задание?

Comment: Я уже примерно это написал двумя сообщениями выше. Вы крайне невнимательны.

Comment: Это всё теоретизация, мне интересно , как вы мыслите в практической плоскости, вы крайне заносчивы и самоуверенны.

Answer (score 2):

В тернарном операторе используются данные одного типа. Нельзя использовать слова типа `break` or `continue`.

Пример использования:

```
$i += $i > 5 ? 1 : 2;
```

Используйте

```
if ($i == 3)
   break;
$i++;
```

Answer (score 0):

`break` не значение.. в тернарном операторе нужно вернуть что-то

Comment: то есть в тернарном операторе можно только переменные возвращать?

Comment: @ВикторВасильев да. только не переменные а expression (выражение), которое может состоять и из одной переменной